# quicksort not working correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, pivot, quicksort, partition

I can't find the problem in my code. It runs, but it can't sort the array correctly. I think the part that most confuse me is how to pass the unsorted subarray in the recursive process.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void quickSort(int*, int, int);
int partition(int*, int, int);

int main(){
    int const size = 10;
    int a[size] = {37, 2, 6, 4, 89, 8, 10, 12, 68, 45};

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    quickSort(a, 0, size-1);
    cout << endl;   
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

}

void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end){
    if(start<end){
        int piv = partition(array, start, end);
        quickSort(array, 0, piv-1);
        quickSort(array, piv+1, end-1);
    }
}

int partition(int *array, int start, int end){
    int piv = array[start];
    int i = start+1;
    int j = end;
    while(i<j){
        while(array[i]<piv and i<end) i++;
        while(array[j]>piv) j--;
        if(i<j){
            int temp = *(array+i);
            *(array+i) = *(array+j);
            *(array+j) = temp;
        }

    }
    int temp = *array;
    *array = *(array+j);
    *(array+j) = temp;
    return j;
}
```

The output is like this:

```
    37 2 6 4 89 8 10 12 68 45
    4 6 8 10 12 37 68 89 2 45
```

Comment: You can view the solution in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504837/how-to-implement-quick-sort-algorithm-in-c

Comment: I'm not so sure that helps the OP with _his_ solution, though. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `end` is *inclusive*, so you should not be recursing on `end-1`, but `end`.

Your `partition()` function makes a couple mistakes:

- In your nested while loop, you should be checking that `i<j`, not `i<end`.
- In your nested while loops, you should *first* check that `i<j` and only then compare the element with `piv`.
- After your loops, you should check to see if `j` points to an element > `piv` or not. If it does, you need to decrement `j` before performing the swap. Consider:

```
     37 2 6 4 12 8 10 89 68 45
                      j
     89 2 6 4 12 8 10 37 68 45
```

- After your loops, you *always* swap with the *first* element in the entire array. I'm sure you *meant* to swap with `array[start]`.

By the way, `*(array+j)` is the same as `array[j]`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that:

```
    quickSort(array, 0, piv-1);
    quickSort(array, piv+1, end-1);
```

should be:

```
    quickSort(array, start, piv-1);  // start, not 0
    quickSort(array, piv+1, end);    // end, not end-1
```

After that, I thought it will be easier to identify the source of the problem by adding `cout` statements in key places in the code. This is what I tried:

```
void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end){

    if(start<end){
       cout << "Before sort: ";
       for(int i=start; i<=end; i++){
          cout << array[i] << " ";
       }
       cout << std::endl;
        int piv = partition(array, start, end);
        std::cout << "Pivot index: " << piv << ", Pivot element: " << array[piv] << std::endl;
        quickSort(array, start, piv-1);
        quickSort(array, piv+1, end);
    }

    cout << "After sort: ";
    for(int i=start; i<=end; i++){
       cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << std::endl;
}
```

With those, I got the following output:

```
37 2 6 4 89 8 10 12 68 45 
Before sort: 37 2 6 4 89 8 10 12 68 45 
Pivot index: 6, Pivot element: 37
Before sort: 10 2 6 4 12 8 
Pivot index: 4, Pivot element: 10
Before sort: 8 2 6 4 
Pivot index: 3, Pivot element: 8
Before sort: 4 2 6 
Pivot index: 1, Pivot element: 4
After sort: 2 
After sort: 6 
After sort: 2 4 6 
After sort: 
After sort: 2 4 6 8 
After sort: 12 
After sort: 2 4 6 8 10 12 
Before sort: 89 68 45 
Pivot index: 9, Pivot element: 2
Before sort: 89 68 
Pivot index: 8, Pivot element: 45
After sort: 89 
After sort: 
After sort: 89 45 
After sort: 
After sort: 89 45 2 
After sort: 68 4 6 8 10 12 37 89 45 2 
68 4 6 8 10 12 37 89 45 2
```

That led me to look closer in `partition` and I noticed that you have:

```
int temp = *array;
*array = *(array+j);
*(array+j) = temp;
```

That explained why a number from the lower half of the partitioned array got pulled into the upper half of the partitioned array. They should be:

```
int temp = *(array+start);
*(array+start) = *(array+j);
*(array+j) = temp;
```

It is more readable to me to use:

```
int temp = array[start];
array[start] = array[j];
array[j] = temp;
```

With those changes, the array came out sorted.